# Operator priority in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am studying on Ivan Bratko book: "Programming for artificial intelligence"

Now I am studying the **operators** and I have some doubts about it, on the book I can read the following thing:

> So the precedence of the operators decides what is the correct interpretation of expressions. For example, the expression **a + b*c** can be, in principle, understood either as:

**1.** `+(a, *(b,c))`

or as:

**2.** `*(+(a,b), c)`

And now I havde the first doubt: "what it means this thing? it seems me very strage because these two expressions give different three and different result !!!

For example if I have: `a=2`, `b=3`, `c=4`

The result of the first one is 14 and the result of the second one is 20 so there are different: different thress means different order of operator execution that means different result !!!

So I think that (using the usual priority of arithmetic operator: execute first the multiplications and after the sums) the correct expression is the first one and the second one is wrong.

Is it correct?

Continuing to read the book I can read also:

> The general rule is that operator with the highest precedence is the principal functor of the term. If expression containing + and * are to be understood according to our normal convention, **then + have a higher precedence then * operator**

and now I have the second doubt: as I said, in normal convention of arithmetic I execute first the multiplications and after the sums,so in my opinion is the * operator that have the precedence and not +

What I am missing about it? Why on the book say that `+` has higher precedence then `*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The principal functor of the term" means the *last* operation to be executed, or the outermost one in prefix notation. This definition is the inverse of yours, thus the contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

> So the precendence of the operators decides what is the correct interpretation of expressions. For example, the expression `a + b*c` can be, in principle, understood either as:
>
> ```
> +(a, *(b,c))
> ```
>
> or as:
>
> ```
> *(+(a,b), c)
> ```

It says that without precedence, those are 2 possible ways to interpret the expression (and different way of parsing the expression will give different result). You only know to group `a + (b * c)` when you know that `*` should be executed before `+`. (I avoid explaining with *precedence* here, since it is confusing as pointed out below).

`+` and `*` are just symbols, and it just happens that they are used as operator with some defined precedence. Generally speaking, you can define anything to be an operator, and give it a precedence.

> The general rule is that operator with the highest precedence is the principal functor of the term. If expression containing `+` and `*` are to be understood according to our normal convention, then `+` have a **higher precedence** than `*` operator

The definition of *precedence* in English is "The condition of being considered more important than someone or something else; priority in importance, order, or rank". As long as something has to happen before some other thing, we have a *precedence*.

In C, [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) is the order of binding in an expression. *Higher precedence* operator in C will get executed before lower precedence operators.

In Prolog, the [precedence](http://www2.gm.fh-koeln.de/Prolog/operators.html) is the order of getting the functor, which is the reverse of the case of C operator's order of binding. Higher *precedence* operator will appear *earlier* when we analyze the expression with [`=..`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.20%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/manipterm.html%27%29%29).